# Backup specific tables in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I know about backing up databases in online and offline mode. I also know about backing up tablespaces in db2. I wanted to know if there's any way we could back up only some specific tables inside a given schema/tablespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to back up individual tables using the BACKUP command. A common approach is to use [EXPORT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) command. If you need to backup the schema, use [db2look](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) to extract the DDL for that table.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't backup specific tables in db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows.